# Вопросик по htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть такой урл mydeomen.com/index.php?q=key-key-key

создал к нему htaccess

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
rewrite (.*).html$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

хотел получить такой вариант (**mydeomen.com/key-key-key.html**), но что-то не выходит

Что я делаю ни так?

Comment: RewruteRule может все таки а не rewrite

Comment: @jikol, уточните что речь идёт о nginx

Comment: Как сделать если есть такой вариант?
test.mydeomen.com/index.php?q=key-key-key

Comment: Вы уточните, какой у вас вебсервер? Apache или Nginx? А то конфиг вы предоставили явно не апачевский...

Comment: Вот этот скрипт явно работает на моем сайте

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*).html index.php?q=$1 [L]

теперь, как изменить если есть subdomain?

 test.mydeomen.com/index.php?q=key-key-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule (.*)\.html index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

(т.е. перед точкой надо поставить `\ (\.html)`

Comment: Что-то не выходит

Comment: а куда нужно перебросить в этом случае?

Comment: test.mydeomen.com/index.php?q=key-key-key

нужно на

test.mydeomen.com/key-key-key.html